# controller is not registered error while running testcase via Jasmine Karma

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write test case for angularjs controller via karma jasmine
Getting below error
Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'ApproveRejectPackageController' is not registered.

This is my controller code and supporting test case

```
(function() {
angular.module('Citi.iv.FC')
.controller('ApproveRejectPackageController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$timeout','$uibModal','$sce', '$stateParams', function ($scope,$filter, $timeout, $uibModal, $sce, $stateParams) {});



describe('myserv', function () {
     var service;
        var data;
        beforeAll(function () { 
            module('Citi.iv.FC')
        }); 
        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope;
            secondController =  $controller('ApproveRejectPackageController', {$scope: scope});
        }));


          it('ServiceTestSpec', function () {
              expect(2 + 3).toBe(6);
          });
});
```

Please suggest how to fix this.
I have included controller in karma-config file

Comment: You are missing the closing square bracket at the end of your controller definition for `ApproveRejectPackageController`

Comment: That is there in original code..any other issue?

Comment: why am i getting module and controller not registered error even when i have mocked it